# What type of doctor is referred to in Breishit 50:2?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, medicine, science, vayechi

[Breishit (Gen.) 50:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=658) uses the term רופאים, which I translate as "doctors". However, within this context, these doctors are embalming Jacob's body. They are not performing the task of healing someone or treating illnesses in the manner that we think of doctors today. (I know that in English, "doctor" is also used for anyone having a PHD, but that's not what I mean, here.)

What type of doctors were these? Can we assume that they also treated illnesses?

Comment: what else could rofim mean if not doctors? that's what the word means everywhere else in the torah no?

Comment: @ray I don't know. But as I ask, it is unclear if these Egyptian doctors also healed people.

Comment: doctors today love to preserve dead bodies

Comment: @ray Is there any reason to think that that might be relevant?

Comment: @mevaqesh thats how they study medicine

Comment: @ray The most I have done in biology is work with dead cats and pigs. I've never studied a dead human. I know this study is commonly done. Are doctors, themselves, involved in body embalmment / preservation? Who typically preserves dead bodies, today?

Comment: Nowadays, pathologists are often MD

Comment: possibly of interest: http://www.history.com/news/ask-history/why-are-barber-poles-red-white-and-blue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In those days, those who were in charge of all medical processes would have handled everything from healing sick people through preparing the person for the after life. Remember, they did not have the split in functions that we do today. In fact, they would have been priests as well. This was Egypt. Also they were the experts in handling the spices and in the procedures for embalming.

[Genesis 50:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8245#v=2&showrashi=true)

> 2 And Joseph commanded his servants, the physicians, to embalm his
>   father, and the physicians embalmed Israel.
>
> ```
>   בוַיְצַו יוֹסֵף אֶת עֲבָדָיו אֶת הָרֹפְאִים לַחֲנֹט אֶת  אָבִיו וַיַּחַנְטוּ הָרֹפְאִים אֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל:
> ```
>
> **Rashi**
>
> to embalm his father: This involves compounding aromatic spices. —
>   [From Targum Jonathan and Targum Yerushalmi]

Additionally, we find from the archeological and historical records that the doctors were the ones who took care of the embalming. They were also the priests who maintained the body since they believed that disease was caused by the gods.

[Ancient Egyptian Medicine:](http://www.ancient.eu/article/50/)

> The Egyptians held the belief that illness was often caused by an
>   angry god or an evil spirit. For this reason, the Egyptian doctor was
>   also part shaman, who performed rituals and recited prayers on the
>   sick. But, the Egyptian physician was not limited to faith healing as
>   part of his or her practice. Egyptian medicine became a far-reaching
>   discipline, encompassing a great many fields. Doctors in Egypt, like
>   today, were specialists in their particular fields. These fields
>   included pharmacology, dentistry, gynecology, crude surgical
>   procedures, general healing, autopsy, and **embalming**.
>
> It is from the process of embalming, or mummification, that Ancient
>   Egyptian physicians gained their greatest knowledge of the human
>   anatomy.

Comment: "In those days, those who were in charge of all medical processes would have handled everything" I would tend to agree but a source for this would be nice. Especially considering that the drasha 
ורפא ירפא was taken to mean medical healing and not spiritual healing.

Comment: Agreeing with above comment. What you wrote is credible, but it's not fully answering the question w/o further support to the 1st paragraph's claim.

Comment: Nowadays anatomopathology is still a part of medical sciences

Comment: @user6591 It is a matter of archeology and history that in Egypt at that time, it was the priests who handled all medical matters including embalming.

Comment: @sabba that's an acceptable point. Link a source and you'll get my upvote:)

Comment: @user6591 I added the citation showing that embalming was on of the specialties in the field of medicine just like any ot the other specialties.